# Calling `tf.keras.Model.save` on a custom model that wraps around an existing `Model`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, serialization

I have a custom `tf.keras.Model` that wraps around an existing model:

```
class MyNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, net):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.net = net
    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.reduce_sum(self.net(inputs), axis=[1, 2])
```

I can instantiate this model for example with an existing model, that I can save, however saving the wrapped model does not work:

```
net = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False)
net.save('net') # works
my_net = MyNet(net)
my_net.save('my_net')
```

will result in an error:

```
ValueError: Model <__main__.MyNet object at 0x7f88fc4de4c0> cannot be saved because the input shapes have not been set. Usually, input shapes are automatically determined from calling `.fit()` or `.predict()`. To manually set the shapes, call `model.build(input_shape)`.
```

Even using

```
my_net.build([None, None, None, 3])
my_net.save('my_net')
```

will result in the same error.

This could be caused by the fact that `net` is already built. How can I tell my wrapped model to be built correctly and use the same input layer as the wrapped model?

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this is to set the `built` flag to `True` since the model wraps around an already built model. Additionally, decorating the `call` function with `tf.function` and providing the input shape does fix the issue:

```
class MyNet(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, net):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.net = net
        self.built = True
    
    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None, None, None, 3], tf.float32)])
    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.reduce_sum(self.net(inputs), axis=[1, 2])
```